# Where to store data values of SNMP MIB objects?

Tags: snmp

Where ever i read MIB files stores objects in a tree like structure, but i didn't find where to store data values of those objects. Is any database required to store data values, if so how to relate OIDs with database tables.

Comment: SNMP MIB defines the interfaces so that an SNMP manager can query the data from objects exposed by an agent. Thus, the actual agent implementation itself should find a way to properly store the data of the objects, and you are free to use any approach feasible. The protocol specification does not set any limitation. You can use database, files, or any other.

Comment: Thank you for your information